# Does AWS SDK TransferManager.Upload delete already uploaded file parts in case of exception occurs?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was reading AWS SDK TransferManager documentation and wasn't able to find out if already uploaded file parts will be deleted in case of any exception during upload. All the examples I've seen so far don't have any cleaning code in case of an exception. If file parts will stay in the bucket it could lead to the money loss especially if files are big.

This is an example from the [amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
    String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
    String keyName = "*** Object key ***";
    String filePath = "*** Path for file to upload ***";

    try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
        TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                .withS3Client(s3Client)
                .build();

        // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
        // so this call returns immediately.
        Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
        System.out.println("Object upload started");

        // Optionally, wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
        upload.waitForCompletion();
        System.out.println("Object upload complete");
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
        // it, so it returned an error response.
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SdkClientException e) {
        // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
        // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Do I need to delete already aploaded file parts in catch block or AWS SDK will manage this fo me?

Comment: Hey Volha, welcome to SO! Please can you add an example of you upload process (any code is always great)

Comment: @MartinCassidy, Just updated, thank you!